# How to download (save in disk) a file that was deleted from server and from cache but is still in memory?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, memory, download, browser-cache

Suppose I opened a video file in a website and  it was deleted from server and from my local cache, but  it is still open and playing on my browser. When I try to download it in Chrome it fails: "Failed - No file".  Is there a way to save this file in disk?

Comment: Short answer: almost impossible. Longer answer: You might be able to write a program that retrieves it from memory but I wouldn't hold my breath.

Comment: To elaborate: the whole file might never be in memory at any one time, i.e. only segments are played sequentially, so for large files, no such program could be created.